How do I calculate the ideal pitch for striking a target with a projectile in a 3D game with increased Z (vertical) velocity?
Some background: The game I'm trying to implement this code in is Quake 2. Based on posts here and elsewhere, I found and implemented the necessary ballistics code, and it works... usually. For some reason, it tends to miss the target when the angle is greater than 33 degrees. Further, there are several weapons that have a higher initial vertical velocity, and I don't know how to adjust the calculations to deal with this.
Here's an example of a weapon firing function with the increased vertical velocity that throws off the ballistics calculations (causing the projectile to fly over the target):
    void fire_lance (edict_t *self, vec3_t start, vec3_t aimdir, int damage, int burn_damage, float speed, float length) {
    edict_t *lance;

    //  entity made a sound, used to alert monsters
    self->lastsound = level.framenum;

    // spawn lance entity
    lance = G_Spawn();
    VectorCopy (start, lance->s.origin);
    lance->movetype = MOVETYPE_TOSS;
    lance->clipmask = MASK_SHOT;
    lance->solid = SOLID_BBOX;
    lance->s.modelindex = gi.modelindex("models/objects/javelin/tris.md2");
    VectorSet(lance->mins, -4, -4, 4);
    VectorSet(lance->maxs, 4, 4, 4);
    lance->owner = self;
    lance->think = lance_think;
    lance->touch = lance_touch;
    lance->dmg_radius = length;
    lance->dmg = damage;
    lance->radius_dmg = burn_damage;
    lance->classname = "lance";
    lance->delay = level.time + 10.0;
    gi.linkentity (lance);
    lance->nextthink = level.time + FRAMETIME;
    vectoangles(aimdir, lance->s.angles);

    // adjust velocity
    VectorScale (aimdir, speed, lance->velocity);
    lance->velocity[2] += 300;
}

Here's the ballistics code (see below). The first function calculates the distance on the horizontal and vertical plane. I've tried two different ways of calculating this, and it doesn't make much of a difference. The second function returns the ideal pitch to strike the target.
void CalculateDisplacement(vec3_t startAngles, vec3_t startPos, vec3_t endPos, float *horizontal, float *vertical)
{
    vec3_t v, xy_v, up;
    VectorSubtract(endPos, startPos, v);
    *vertical = v[2];
    AngleVectors(startAngles, NULL, NULL, up);
    ProjectOnPlane(xy_v, v, up);
    *horizontal = VectorLength(xy_v);
}

// returns the ideal pitch angle to hit an enemy with a projectile with a fixed speed of v
//FIXME: the calculation tends to miss the mark when enemy is far away and when the short angle is >33 degrees
// it also misses when the vertical projectile speed is different from horizontal speed
float BOT_DMclass_ThrowingPitch1(edict_t* self, float v)
{
    vec3_t offset, forward, right, start;
    VectorSet(offset, 8, 8, self->viewheight - 8);
    AngleVectors(self->client->v_angle, forward, right, NULL);
    P_ProjectSource(self->client, self->s.origin, offset, forward, right, start);

    float g = sv_gravity->value;
    float d;// = Get2dDistance(start, self->enemy->s.origin);//Horizontal distance to the target.
    float h;// = self->enemy->s.origin[2] - start[2]; //Vertical difference between the projectile's initial height and the target height.

    CalculateDisplacement(self->s.angles, self->s.origin, self->enemy->s.origin, &d, &h);
    double discriminant = pow(v, 4) - g * (g * pow(d, 2) + (2 * h * pow(v, 2)));

    if (discriminant <= 0)
    {
        gi.dprintf("%s: target can't be reached @ %f\n", __func__, d);
        return -999; // target can't be reached
    }

    float angle1 = atan((-pow(v, 2) + sqrt(discriminant)) / (-g * d)) * (180 / M_PI);
    float angle2 = atan((-pow(v, 2) - sqrt(discriminant)) / (-g * d)) * (180 / M_PI);

    angle1 *= -1;
    angle2 *= -1;
    if (angle1 < -33)
        angle1 -= 3; // small adjustment for far-away targets that tend to come up short
    //if (angle1 < -33) // use high angle for far-away targets
    //  return angle2;//FIXME: need to check vertical clearance before doing this, otherwise we hit the sky!
    //else
        return angle1;
}

My math skills aren't strong, so if you have any ideas, please include code modifications or pseudocode, thank you!

Does the 3D ballistic code at the bottom of this answer help you?

Which part? There's a lot of code in the link to parse. It looks like you've got some code to help me find an arc below ceiling height, which I might try later. But I run into issues even with the low angle result. I tried using both atan and atan2, with both returning similar angles that end up missing the target at angles >33 degrees. And I have no idea how to deal with increased vertical velocity.

The block of code at the bottom of the answer calculates the launch velocity without needing atan or atan2.

I see that, but how does it help me solve my problem? I don't want to change the weapon projectile velocity (that would be "cheating"), I want to know the ideal firing pitch.

The velocity is a vector pointing along the angle you want. Convert it to spherical coordinates and you get your pitch value. You can subtract the extra vertical velocity from the vector before you do the conversion to compensate for that addition.

I've got this implemented but it tends to come up short when the pitch is less than -12 (tilting up and using t_min). Also, how would I change the inputs with the increased vertical velocity?

Why the Standard Ballistic Formula Fails with Extra Vertical Velocity and How to Fix It
The standard ballistic formulas (which assume a uniform initial speed \$v\$ tend to overshoot when angles exceed 33 degrees. Below is an explanation of why it happens and how to fix it by solving for the launch angle numerically.

1. The Standard Formula Assumes a Single Launch Speed
The “textbook” projectile formula for an ideal angle \$\theta\$ is:
$$
\theta \;=\; \arctan\!\Bigl(
  \frac{v^2 
    \pm \sqrt{\,v^4 - g\bigl(g\,d^2 + 2\,h\,v^2\bigr)}
  }{g\,d}
\Bigr)
$$
That formula assumes:

The projectile is launched with total speed \$v\$ at angle \$\theta\$.
The vertical component is \$v \sin(\theta)\$.
No extra offset to the vertical velocity.

However, in this Quake 2 mod, the actual vertical component is:
velocity[z] = v * sin(θ) + 300

This extra constant +300 breaks the standard formula.

2. The Correct 2D Equations
Reducing the motion to the 2D plane (horizontal distance d, height offset h), let \$\theta\$ be the unknown pitch. Then:
x(t) = (speed * cos(θ)) * t
z(t) = (speed * sin(θ) + 300) * t - (1/2) * g * t^2

We want \$x(t) = d\$ and \$z(t) = h\$. From \$x(t) = d\$:
t = d / (speed * cos(θ))

Plugging that into the z(t) equation:
h = (speed * sin(θ) + 300) * (d / [speed * cos(θ)])
    - (1/2) * g * (d / [speed * cos(θ)])^2

Rearrange that to isolate terms:
h = d * tan(θ)
    + (300 * d) / [speed * cos(θ)]
    - (g * d^2) / [2 * speed^2 * cos^2(θ)]

Call the right-hand side \$F(\theta)\$. We need \$F(\theta) - h = 0\$. There's no simple closed-form for \$\theta\$ once you add a constant +300 to the vertical velocity.

3. Solving Numerically (Binary Search Example)
A straightforward fix is to use a binary search for \$\theta\$. We define a helper function F_of_theta that computes \$F(\theta) - h\$. Then we adjust \$\theta\$ until it zeroes out. Below is C++-like pseudocode:
// Evaluate [F(θ) - h]:
float F_of_theta(float degTheta,
                 float d, float h,
                 float speed, float offsetZ, // e.g. 300
                 float g)
{
    // Convert degrees -> radians
    float rad = degTheta * (3.14159f / 180.0f);
    float c   = cos(rad);
    float s   = sin(rad);

    // F(θ) = d * tan(θ)
    //      + (offsetZ * d)/(speed * cos(θ))
    //      - (g * d^2)/(2 * speed^2 * cos^2(θ))
    float term1 = d * (s / c);
    float term2 = (offsetZ * d) / (speed * c);
    float term3 = (g * d * d) / (2.0f * speed * speed);

    float Ftheta = term1 + term2 - term3 * (1.0f / (c * c));
    return (Ftheta - h);
}

float SolvePitchForBallistic(float d,
                             float h,
                             float speed,
                             float offsetZ, // e.g. +300
                             float g)
{
    float low       = -89.0f;
    float high      =  89.0f;
    float bestPitch =  0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        float mid  = 0.5f * (low + high);
        float fMid = F_of_theta(mid, d, h, speed, offsetZ, g);

        // If F_of_theta(mid) > 0, we're overshooting => reduce pitch
        if (fMid > 0.0f)
            high = mid;
        else
            low = mid;

        bestPitch = mid;
    }

    return bestPitch;
}

After ~32 iterations, bestPitch will be the angle (in degrees) that precisely makes the projectile land at the correct height offset h, despite the extra +300 vertical velocity.

4. Summary

Issue: A constant +300 vertical boost invalidates the standard projectile formula.
Fix: Solve the actual 2D equations, which typically requires numerical methods (binary search, Newton’s method, etc.).
Implementation: Compute the correct pitch by searching for \$\theta\$ that zeroes out \$F(\theta) - h\$.

Using this method, your projectile should land accurately on the target even when you add a constant vertical velocity beyond the normal \$v \sin(\theta)\$.

Pro Tip: If you only call SolvePitchForBallistic once per shot or per AI decision, the binary search overhead is negligible in a Quake 2 mod context.

